# How to create a Dynamin form field in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

How can i create a Dynamic List down in Joomla?
Eg: I have departments and relevant sub-departments, so i want to create a drop down to select sub-departments according to the Department selected.

any Help please?

Comment: In which section do you want to show dropdowns?

Comment: well, in the HTML form. There is a search area in that form with 3 drop downs, 1. Department, 2. Sub Department and 3. Location. So users should be able to select "Department" first and then second drop down should fill sub-departments according to the 1st department selection. Department and sub-Department data is available in 2 sql tables.

Comment: This information - it's part of some your module/component?